# How do you handle two or more connected list view (1 activity for all or 1 activity per list view?)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I know this could be just a matter of taste, but would be happy if anyone could comment about the subject. I have 3 list views connected. By connected I mean first list has 3 items if I click on first item it leads me to second list and if I click on the first item of second list it leads to third list.

How do people ussually do this? Would you use just one activity and handle everything by this activity or create an activity for every list?

Answer (score 1):

This really IS a matter of preference.

In similar situation (1 list for galleries, 1 for images) I used fragments.
1 fragment provides to user list of all the galleries and has a listener which notifies when 1 of the items is clicked (gallery is chosen).

The other fragment provides list of images in a gallery and has a setter for gallery id (only 1 fragment instance is used for this one, images can be changed by setting other gallery id).

This way, those lists are actually independent of each other and can be used as separate UI elements if I'll need some other gallery picker in other place (gridview for example).

This is also very useful in tablet versions, since you can place 2 fragments in the same activity, and, I believe, is preferred way to do such things.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using 3 different activity to show the 3 different list. Only reason being that using different activities would give me a clean back-button-click process. You may use the same activity (changing the adapter as the user click the list item) but the back button operation will result in showing the previous activity and not the previous list.

Reading your problem description I suppose you may even try using ContextMenu/Dialogs to show the 2nd and 3rd list assuming that these list may contain choices that the user is supposed to select.